# Python: Create strikethrough / strikeout / overstrike string type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would appreciate some help in creating a function that iterates through a string and combines each character with a strikethrough character (\u0336). With the output being a striked out version of the original string. <strike>Like this.</strike>.

Something like.

```
def strike(text):
    i = 0
    new_text = ''
    while i < len(text):
        new_text = new_text + (text[i] + u'\u0336')
        i = i + 1
    return(new_text)
```

So far I've only been able to concatenate rather than combine.

Comment: I think you meant to put quotes around `\u0336`. I take it you're getting a SyntaxError?

Comment: Good spot. Edited it to `u'\u0336'`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
def strike(text):
    result = ''
    for c in text:
        result = result + c + '\u0336'
    return result
```

Cool effect.

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid. I was trying this but the output _looked_ concatenated in the IDE Shell. But sure enough when copied and pasted to a text editor the characters are striked through. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

How about:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(text, repeat('\u0336'))))
```

or even more simply,

```
'\u0336'.join(text) + '\u0336'
```

Comment: You should actually _prepend_ the control character.

Comment: this: `'\u0336'.join(text) + '\u0336'` also seems to miss the first character of the string?

Comment: I had to use `'\u0336' + '\u0336'.join(text)`, instead of `'\u0336'.join(text) + '\u0336'`. I think the Unicode standard is that the modifying character goes after the base letter, but it isn't working that way when I try. I had to put the modifying character first.

Answer (score 6):

**Edited**

As pointed out by [roippi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581969/roippi) other answers so far are actually correct, and this one below is wrong. Leaving it here in case others get the same wrong idea that I did.

---

Other answers so far are wrong - they do not strike out the first character of the string. Try this instead:

```
def strike(text):
    return ''.join([u'\u0336{}'.format(c) for c in text])

>>> print(strike('this should do the trick'))
'̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶c̶k'
```

This will work in Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I assure you that that is the spec.  I can't help with your rendering issue other than to suggest you get a more unicode-compliant font/terminal.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, but could you provide a reference to the spec please?

Comment: [here you go](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch02.pdf), ctrl-f for Sequence of Base Characters and Diacritics.  `In the Unicode Standard, all combining characters are to be used in sequence following the
base characters to which they apply.`

Comment: Thanks for that- you're right of course... I'll have to go and figure out why it's not rendering properly for me.

Comment: It's missing the u'\u0336{}' before the first character. Just add it to the beginning of what you're returning, `return u'\u0336{}' + ''.join(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Although `'\u0336'` can solve some problems, it may not work in different language situations.

Like: 我是誰 → ̶我̶是̶誰.

As you can see, the otherwise good text has turned into strange symbols that we can't read.

So I write the code below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

class strikethrough(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, frame, text, **options):
        super().__init__(frame)
        c = tk.Canvas(self, **options)
        textId = c.create_text(0, 0, text = text, fill = "#FFFFFF", font = ("", 30, "bold"))
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.bbox(textId)
        linewidth = 3
        lineXOffset = 3
        lineId = c.create_line(x1, 0, x2, 0, width=linewidth)
        c.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        c.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: TextPositionChange(c, textId, lineId, linewidth, lineXOffset))
        self.canvas, self.textId = c, textId


def TextPositionChange(canvas, TextId, LineId, LineWidth, LineXOffset):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(TextId)
    xOffSet, yOffSet = (x2-x1)/2, (y2-y1)/2
    x, y = canvas.winfo_width()/2-xOffSet, canvas.winfo_height()/2-yOffSet #left_top_position
    canvas.moveto(TextId, x, y)
    canvas.moveto(LineId, x-LineXOffset, y+(y2-y1)/2-LineWidth/2)

frame = strikethrough(root, "我是誰", bg="#777777")
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.5, anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include spaces in the strikethrough, you'll have to replace normal spaces with non-break spaces:

```
def strikethrough(mytext):
    ''' replacing space with 'non-break space' and striking through'''
    return("\u0336".join(mytext.replace(" ","\u00a0"))+ "\u0336")
```